# Every concave function that is nonnegative on its domain is log-concave?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

This is a statment from Wiki. I'm not sure why this is true:

If: $f(\theta x+(1-\theta y) \geq \theta f( x) + (1-\theta)f(y)$
And $f(\cdot) \geq 0$ then:

$$f(\theta x+(1-\theta y) \geq  f( x)^{\theta}f(y)^{1-\theta}$$

I guess we should prove that:

$$\theta f( x) + (1-\theta)f(y) \geq f( x)^{\theta}f(y)^{1-\theta}$$

Don't have idea how to prove that.

Comment: For that, forget about $f$ and prove $\theta a + (1-\theta)b \geqslant a^\theta b^{1-\theta}$ for $a,b \geqslant 0$. The case $\theta = \frac{1}{2}$ is a familiar inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $\log$ is a concave function,
$$
\log (\theta a + (1-\theta)b )\ge \theta \log a + (1-\theta)\log b
$$

Now with $$
a=f(x);b = f(y)
$$it follows that

$$
\log f(\theta a + (1-\theta)b) \ge \theta \log f(x)+ (1-\theta)\log f(y)
$$

---

More generally, if $f$ is concave with values in $D\subset \Bbb R$ and $g$ is concave increasing 
and define on $D$ then $g\circ f$ is concave as well: it is the same proof.

Answer (score 2):

This is the so-called "weighted arithmetic mean geometric mean inequality".  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Weighted_AM.E2.80.93GM_inequality